# watchOS app resets to root view controller after display sleep

Tags: watchkit, watchos, wkinterfacecontroller

I'm implementing a simple hierarchical interface for a watchOS app, using `pushController(withName: String, context: Any?)` to add views onto the stack. When trying to test on a watchOS 3 device, my app will reset itself back to the root view controller, losing the navigation state, after a "sleep" event.

Is this expected behavior? I would expect the navigation state to reset if the app was purged from memory, but not after the screen goes to sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the app target to watchOS 3 and implementing the [`handle(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkextensiondelegate/1650877-handle) WKExtensionDelegate method (which I had not done, since the watchOS targets were generated under Xcode 7) seems to provide the behavior I expected.